# how to access a parent's operator in cpp

Tags: c++

I have made a class whose parent has an operator and i've been trying to access that parent's operator.
I couldn't find an answer online about how i should go about doing it. 
Is there anyone that knows?
Thanks in advance.
code:
The operator in out stream is delared in the following manner:

> ( OutStream& operator<<(const char *str);)

The class outStreamencrypted is a child element of outstream:

> (class OutStreamEncrypted : OutStream)

the new operator in outstreamencrypted is delared the following way and what im trying to do is use the operator in outstream in this new operator.

```
 OutStreamEncrypted& OutStreamEncrypted::operator<<(const char* str)
        {
            int i = 0;
            char* newStr = NULL;
            while ((str + i) != NULL)
            {
                if (*(str + i) >= 32 && *(str + i) <= 126)
                {
                    *(newStr + i) = *(str + i) + _ceasarValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    *(newStr + i) = *(str + i);
                }
                i++;
            }
            *(newStr + i) = NULL;
```

I'm trying to call the parent, OutStream, operator which prints a string into a file.

Comment: 'parent' = . 'base class'?

Comment: Have a look at how to make a [mcve]. I'm guessing you are talking about an operator in `OutStream`? Which operator? Where are you trying to access it? What is the error you are getting? Why is this question lacking a main function? Etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking the operator as a function should be OK

```
OutStreamEncrypted& OutStreamEncrypted::operator<<(const char* str)
{
  ...
  OutStream::operator<<( some_value_to_inject );
  ...
}
```